# unable to ssh into GCP VM instance using custom mode VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-vpc

I have created VPC in custom mode and added a subnet in the us-central region. Then I created a VM instance in the same us-central region and then I have set the  firewall rule as shown in the image but I am unable to ssh into that VM. What could be the issue?

[firewall rule i added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxzTY.png)

[created vm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrpU6.png)

[image: issue iam getting]

Comment: I think you need to allow the IP ranges of the VM. Also when trying to SSH do you ssh to the external IP of the VM?

Comment: Please check official documentation about [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh). Make sure default Firewall rules for SSH exists: ```default-allow-ssh```. And from your firewall rules added, I see an error because ping it's ICMP protocol not TCP or UDP.

Comment: Are you trying to reach the VM from the defined range?

Comment: Thanks for all ur cmts. i made mistake in firewall rule, after updating rule its working

Answer (score 1):

This error is almost all the time related to the lack of a firewall rule or the firewall rule you have created it's wrong configured.

In the image of your firewall rule I don't see the target specified for this connection.

Double-check your firewall rule and it will work.